# linux kernel configuration to filter multicast traffic based on interface

Tags: networking, multicast, linux-kernel, interface

I have two virtual interfaces (eth0.2, eth0.3) in my PC. I am sending multicast data from eth0.2 to eth0.2. Multicast data is received in eth0.2 but also received in eth0.3, the other virtual interface.

After a study I understand that Linux kernel should filter the received multicast packets based on the interface and send to appropriate interface.

Is my above understanding correct?

How to configure the linux kernel to receive multicast packet only on particular interface?
How can I prevent the unintended interface from receiving duplicate packets?